# How could I anime a SVG inside an object tag?

Tags: javascript, svg, anime.js

I'm trying to anime an svg image inside an object tag via anime.js
This is what i found on internet+mycode:

```
<object id="object1" type="image/svg+xml" data="./image.svg"><object>
<script>
window.onload=()=>{
    var o = document.getElementById('object1');
    var svg=o.contentDocument();
    var element=svg.getElementById('circle');
    anime({
        targets: element,
        translateY: [0, 260],
        direction: 'alternate',
        duration: 2000,
        easing: 'linear',
        loop: true
    })
}</script>
```

SVG Code:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmnls:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="157.627px" height="925.421px" viewBox="0 0 157.627 925.421" enable-background="nee 0 0 157.627 925.421" xml:space="preserve">
<circle id="circle" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="5" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="81.355" cy="842.37" r="50"/>
</svg>
```

With the SVG inside the HTML file, all works fine, so isn't a problem of anime.js.

Comment: Implement the animation in SMIL directly in the SVG.

Comment: @Robert Longson if possible i prefer without SMIL

Comment: i just love **animeing** svg's <3